# Improving reading speed for complex material for already high comprehenders by eliminating mental vocalization?

Tags: reading

I'm a heavy reader, but my reading is limited primarily to non-fiction and scientific material. I find that my speed is becoming a real hinderance and is starting to discourage consumption. Comprehension and recall are excellent; speed is the bottleneck.

***I'm not seeking to "speed read" (skim, etc.), but rather to improve my intake rate while maintaining comprehension.***

When I read I find that I have at least two primary difficulties (probably more, but these are what I mainly notice):

1. I vocalize what I read. This of course greatly slows me down (*perhaps this helps in comprehension, but I can't believe it does entirely since the mind can process data more rapidly in a visual fashion*).
2. I find myself lost in thought sometimes both about the material AND
   occasionally other things.

It's clear that if I could eliminate these two issues I could dramatically increase my speed.

Are there any specific techniques available to help in these areas, perhaps especially in eliminating vocalization?

Perhaps there are other areas of improvement as well that could help, while reading such material. Any techniques or studies that have proven helpful in establishing good reading behavior and habits?